# how to read an Excel file (.XLSX/XLS) with no libraries in JS

Tags: javascript, excel

what is the native way to do this operation?

I tried this code but it outputs me Gibrish lines .

```
const input = document.getElementById('my_file_input');
input.addEventListener('change',(e)=> {
    
    const fr = new FileReader();
    
    fr.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('my_file_output').textContent = this.result;
    console.log(fr.result)
    }
    fr.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    
},false);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use

```
fs.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0])
```

To get the actual byte data (the "gibberish lines") then to get the text you have to look up the File Specification for XLS files to know what bytes represent what, then when you find the right ones call `Strint.fromCharCode' on each byte then join them together